# Mysql design for a user with several items of data

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to store notes, bookmarks, videos and images that belong to a user:

The simplified user table is as follows:

```
user: id, email, password_hash
```

A note contains a title and content, whereas a bookmark contains a title and a url

```
note: id, title, content, (user_id)
bookmark: id, title, uri
video: id, title, uri
images: id, title, uri
```

I could create a table for all these, however If I wanted to add something else, for example  tasks, I would have to create another table for this. How do you suggest I design the tables?

Is mysql the best db for this, Or would something like `mongodb` be better?

Comment: Could you have one table with `id, title, content` and `user_id`, with `content` as a generic field? Then add another field specifying the type of content that row defines.

Comment: What is the scope of uniqueness of `title` - globally unique, unique per content type, unique per user or unique per combination of user and content type? Will there be any fields other than `url` in content? Are you using InnoDB (so clustering is an issue)? Do you need ability to specify new content types without changing the database model?

Comment: a) unique per content type, b) timestamp, deleted (bool) c) No I'm not using InnoDB.

Comment: @johnmossel Will there ever be different fields for different types of content? Also, can a content be shared among users (e.g. two users having same image)?

Comment: No users cannot share. Content is either a URI or text.

Answer (score 0):

As JamWaffles suggests you could have one table for content and one for content types, i.e.:

```
content: id, title, uri, content_type_id, user_id
content_type: id, name
```

EDIT: The content table could look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| id |   title   |     uri      | content_type_id | user_id |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 'My note' | '/note?id=1' |        4        |    56   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the content type table:

```
---------------
| id |  name  |
---------------
| 4  | 'note' |
---------------
```

I haven't actually used MongoDB but I guess you could use the following structure:

```
{
  "id": "...",
  "email": "...",
  "password_hash": "...",
  "notes": {
    "id": "...",
    "title": "...",
    "uri": "..."
  }
  "bookmarks": {
     ...
  }
}
```

MongoDB like other NoSQL databases have their advantages as well as disadvantages. You would have to evaluate your specific needs in order to determine which better suite yours. Personally I don't see why you couldn't use mysql for your proprosed database structure.

I hope this helps,
Per Flitig
Netlight Consulting

Comment: What happens to the note content then? Shall I create a separate table for that?

Comment: In the mysql case you'd have the notes in the table `content`. An example row in `content` could be `{123, 'My note', '/note?id=1', 4, 56}` with the corresponding row in `content_type`, `{4, 'note'}`